# Uninstall Open JDK Zulu - Install Oracle JDK / Mac

Tags: java, macos, azul-zulu

I'm having some problems trying to install the last version of Oracle Java JDk on my Mac running macOS Catalina 10.15.7.
Brief, when I use the java -version command I get this information:
[image: Java Version on my Mac]

I never ever installed Zulu, does it come with the Mac or do I have it because I have anaconda navigator? Sorry but I don't use very often Java, I'm more a Python person

Anyways, I also tried to uninstall Java completely and install Java from scratch, but I still get that version and Zulu.

I would be extremely grateful if someone could tell how to get rid of Zulu or if I can use Oracle Java JDK without uninstalling Zulu.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Check https://docs.azul.com/zulu/zuludocs/ZuluUserGuide/UninstallingZulu/UninstallZulu_MacOSX.htm

Comment: I did it, and in the folder Virtual Machine the only folder there is: jdk-15.0.1.jdk

Comment: try `which java` to find where this Zulu installation resides

Comment: Thank you, I found Zulu in the Anaconda folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

Comment: WARNING: That deletes a lot more than just on JDK ...

Comment: Yep, it will delete non-zulu SDKs as well if you are not careful. Dr Neo's answer should be the accepted one

Answer (score 6):

The website uninstall page is changed to this:

https://docs.azul.com/core/zulu-openjdk/uninstall/macos

Launch Terminal and navigate to the `JavaVirtualMachines` directory:

```bash
    cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
    # Display the list of directories:
```

```bash
    % ls -1
    zulu-11.jdk
    zulu-13.jre
    zulu-15.jdk
```

Each directory corresponds to a version of Azul Zulu.

To uninstall a specific version of Azul Zulu, use the following command:

```bash
sudo rm -rf <zulu_directory>
# For example, to uninstall Azul Zulu 11 JDK, run:
sudo rm -rf zulu-11.jdk
```

### Note

There are two other locations that should not be `rm` as they are shipped with the `macOS` these are

```bash
# java_home
/usr/libexec
# java 
/usr/bin/ 
# try to find them using 
# at /usr/bin/ for example
#/usr/bin
ls -lgh | grep java | xargs -I {}
# you will get all the wheel 
-rwxr-xr-x 52 wheel 164K May 10 06:30 java
-rwxr-xr-x 52 wheel 164K May 10 06:30 javac
-rwxr-xr-x 52 wheel 164K May 10 06:30 javadoc
-rwxr-xr-x 52 wheel 164K May 10 06:30 javah
-rwxr-xr-x 52 wheel 164K May 10 06:30 javap
-rwxr-xr-x 52 wheel 164K May 10 06:30 javapackager
-rwxr-xr-x 52 wheel 164K May 10 06:30 javaws
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference - in ubuntu 18.04 - the following would do:

`rm -rf /usr/lib/jvm/*zulu*`

`rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/zulu*`